# Is it possible to bulk follow work items in TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

I want to follow several work items and to be able to do this in bulk rather than having to go into each item and click 'follow'. I have created a query but can't see a way of getting updates on the status of each item within the query. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't the feature for now, there are two user voices to suggest the feature , you can go and vote them up to achieve it in future:

User Voice:

- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/16650295-i-can-t-seem-to-bulk-follow-items
- https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13885038-assign-followers-to-a-work-item

As a workaround, you can create a notification alert for the work items change. See [Set alerts, get notified when changes occur](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) for details.